# Limitation of read child from Firebase onValueChanged Event to how many simultaneously connected users at the same time?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase in Unity3d. According to firebase doc they say cloud function can only be triggered 1000. 
Is that mean only 1000 connected(at the same time) users event can be read ? Then What if I have 20K connected(at the same time) users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1000 concurrent managed server instances handling events for a single function.  This has nothing to do with the number of concurrent users in your system.  A concurrent user doesn't have to be generating events that would be handled by Cloud Function.  Unless you've developed your app with a serious bug, I find it highly improbable that one user would be dominating the load on one server instance.

Unless your users are generating *extremely* high numbers of events that needs to be handled by a single deployed function, you almost certainly don't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) in my application concurrent users only read child from onValueChanged event when admin updates a child. Will all concurrent users (more than 1000)  can read child from onValueChanged event ?

Comment: Yes, Realtime Database has very different limitations.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Comment: If this was helpful, please accept the answer as correct.